# On back press shifts control to previous activity, but view of previous activity displaying very slow

Tags: android, onbackpressed

OnBackPressed() function is working fine, but when I show the interstitial ad, I put **onAdClose** listener, and when user close the ad, I am just moving back to previous activity. Problem is that control immediately moves back to previous activity, **BUT** view of previous activity displays after sometime, 3-10 seconds. I am pasting code, let me know if there is problem with anAdClose() listener or something else? Thank You

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    if (activityCount > 4) {
        if(commonInterstitialAd.isLoaded()){
            commonInterstitialAd.show();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }
        commonInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                activityCount = 0;
                activity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        });
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: It may be because listener is getting called late(Check for it). If this is the problem you should show add on previous activity's `onActivityResult()` Use `startActivityForResult()` to open the next `Activity`. Also debug your `onBackPress()` code I think your ad is showing multiple times .

Comment: @ADM I am not too sure, but yes I think listener is the culprit for freezing view, now I put super.onBackPressed() after ad.show(), and its working.... Still not cofirm whether it was ad listener or what.